# Why does the Nexus Artifact Uploader store artifacts in a separate directory?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-plugins, nexus

I want to publish an artifact to Nexus 3 in the Gradle project.
Due to requirements, publish from Jenkins instead of gradle publish using build.gradle maven-publish plug-in.
I created and executed a JenkinsPipeline script, but the artifact jar and pom have been separated.Why?

The following site is referred to [this](https://dzone.com/articles/jenkins-publish-maven-artifacts-to-nexus-oss-using) and [this](https://dzone.com/articles/jenkins-publish-maven-artifacts-to-nexus-oss-using).

https://plugins.jenkins.io/nexus-artifact-uploader

And I make JenkinsPipeline script.

floowing pipeline script.

```
pipeline {
    ...
        stage("publish to nexus") {
            steps {
                script {
                    pom = readMavenPom file: "build/pom.xml";
                    artifactPath = "build/libs/gs-managing-transactions-0.1.0.jar"
                    artifactExists = fileExists artifactPath;
                    if(artifactExists) {
                        nexusArtifactUploader(
                            nexusVersion: NEXUS_VERSION,
                            protocol: NEXUS_PROTOCOL,
                            nexusUrl: NEXUS_URL,
                            groupId: pom.groupId,
                            version: pom.version,
                            repository: NEXUS_REPOSITORY,
                            credentialsId: NEXUS_CREDENTIAL_ID,
                            artifacts: [
                                [artifactId: pom.artifactId, classifier: '', file: artifactPath   , type: pom.packaging],
                                [artifactId: pom.artifactId, classifier: '', file: "build/pom.xml", type: "pom"]
                            ]
                        );

                    } else {
                        error "*** File: ${artifactPath}, could not be found";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ...
}
```

part of execute log

```
[Pipeline] nexusArtifactUploader
...
Uploading: http://localhost:7777/repository/maven-snapshots/com/sample/sample-spring-managing-transactions/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/sample-spring-managing-transactions-0.0.1-20190621.123700-7-debug.jar
...
Uploading artifact gs-managing-transactions-0.1.0.jar completed.
...
Uploading: http://localhost:7777/repository/maven-snapshots/com/sample/sample-spring-managing-transactions/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/sample-spring-managing-transactions-0.0.1-20190621.123701-8-debug.pom
Uploading artifact pom.xml completed.
```

Why stored separete artifact like "sample-spring-managing-transactions-0.0.1-20190621.123700-7-debug.jar", "sample-spring-managing-transactions-0.0.1-20190621.123701-8-debug.pom".

I will expect following.

"sample-spring-managing-transactions-0.0.1-20190621.123700-7-debug.jar" "sample-spring-managing-transactions-0.0.1-20190621.123701-7-debug.pom"

Answer (score 0):

solved. I missed the description "Uploading maven artifacts snapshots is not supported by this plugin." plugins.jenkins.io/nexus-artifact-uploader.